# How to use JQuery-Inputmask to validate email addresses?

Tags: regex, xml, jquery-inputmask

I want to validate an email. I know how to do it in python code, but I want to do this using XML, below is my XML field:

```
name="email" widget="regex_mask" data-inputmask-regex='[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}' context="{'gravatar_image': True}"
```

This is not working on email, I have also used:

```
widget="regex_mask"  data-inputmask-regex="^\d+$"
```

On char filed, and it is working fine.

It would not take any character from the keyboard.
If anyone knows how to do this... please let me know, I'm waiting for your answer :)
Thanks.

Comment: *"his is not working"* means nothing. Describe what's not working: the input you have tried, your expectations, what happens instead, any errors you got.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery-Inputmask has [a built-in `email` mask extension](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/61202246155b8b46e05abae4ec4a2cdfe69fc926/README.md#aliases).

So instead of your `data-inputmask-regex` attribute, you should be able to just replace it with

```
data-inputmask-alias="email"
```